# Swiper.js - how to show 2 half slides and 2 full slides

Tags: slider, swiper.js

I'm wanting to use swiper.js and show 2 full slides in the center and then a half slide either side. I assume this is possible but can't work out how.

Can anyone advise? Want to recreate the below.

[image]

thanks!

Answer (score 8):

If you want to show 1 Slide Full and 2nd slide half
you can use the config like

slidesPerView: 1.2,
Working in swiper version 8.3

Answer (score 5):

**No way to center `two slides` like this (The [centeredSlides](https://swiperjs.com/swiper-api#param-centeredSlides) ralted to active slide (one slide)).**

"hack" idea - use 4 slides per view and add **negative left/right margin** `div` around swiper.

To avoid overflow-x issue this should be the structure:

```
div (overflow-x: hidden;)
--- extra wrapper (with negative l/r margin)
------ swiper
```

** the "build in `next/prev` arrows will break (You should edit the core CSS -or- use custom next/prev).

**Snippet:**

```css
body {
  background: #eee;
  margin: 0px;
  font-size: 14px;
  color: #000;

}

b{
  color: red;
}

.swiper {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.swiper-slide {
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 18px;
  background: #fff;
  /* Center slide text vertically */
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  height: 120px!important;
  align-items: center;
}


main{
  margin-right: -10%;
  margin-left: -10%;
}

/* fix arrows position */
.swiper-button-next{
  right: 10%!important;
}

.swiper-button-prev{
  left: 10%!important;
}
```

```html
<!-- Link Swiper's CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/swiper/swiper-bundle.min.css" />

<body>
  <br>
  <!-- Swiper -->
  <div style="overflow-x: hidden;">
  <main>
    <div class="swiper mySwiper">
      <div class="swiper-wrapper">
        <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 1</div>
        <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 2 - <b>center</b></div>
        <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 3 - <b>center</b></div>
        <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 4</div>
        <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 5</div>
        <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 6</div>
        <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 7</div>
        <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 8</div>
        <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 9</div>
      </div><!-- end swiper wrapper-->
      
  <!-- If we need navigation buttons -->
  <div class="swiper-button-prev"></div>
  <div class="swiper-button-next"></div>
    </div><!-- end swiper -->
  </main>
  </div>

  <!-- Swiper JS -->
  <script src="https://unpkg.com/swiper/swiper-bundle.min.js"></script>

  <!-- Initialize Swiper -->
  <script>
    var swiper = new Swiper(".mySwiper", {
      slidesPerView: 4,
      slidesPerGroup: 1,
      centeredSlides: false,
      loop: true,
      slideToClickedSlide: true,
      spaceBetween: 10,
      pagination: {
        el: ".swiper-pagination",
        clickable: true,
      },
        // Navigation arrows
  navigation: {
    nextEl: '.swiper-button-next',
    prevEl: '.swiper-button-prev',
  },
    });
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Related: https://css-tricks.com/negative-margins/

Comment: ```<div class="swiper-wrapper" style="margin: 0 -10%">``` Is the fast way, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 3):

One way I found to have worked quite well was to do the following:

```
.swiper-container {
  overflow: visible;
  width: 70%;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto
}
```

Then in the swiper config:

```
loop: true,
loopedSlides: 4, #set to your total number of slides
slidesPerView: 2,
```

That gives this effect:

[image: Browser dev tools showing screenshot of Swiper layout for center positioning two slides with a side overflow]

What you're essentially doing here is centering the entire swiper container but allowing items to overflow the container. The `width: 70%` in the CSS snippet above could be adjusted to show slightly less or more of each image on the left and right. Even if you click and drag outside the slider container (highlighted in blue above) Swiper will still continue to behave as normal and move the next elements into and out of view.

The reason `loopedSlides` is needed here is because if it is not set, once you hit the end of your slides (and the right side is set to show the first slide in the loop) Swiper seems to not realise this and there will be a blank space to the very right where the first slide should show. If you tell Swiper the amount of slides you have it seems to do a better job of calculating this and will load it correctly when you hit the end. It is probably something to do with the width & centering in the CSS that it trips up on however setting this property works well. I'm using Swiper V6 but it may have been fixed in newer versions. Play with it and see if it's needed.

Have fun!

Answer (score 0):

I build a Function that toggles a Css Class with `padding-left: 10%`

Here is my Slider Config with the Function:

```
const sliderConfiguration: SliderProps = {
arrows: hasArrows,
dots: hasDots && !isMobileSize,
onSliderMove: updateSliderClass,
onNavigationNext: updateSliderClass,
onNavigationPrev: updateSliderClass,
slidesPerView: 2.5,
};
  
const updateSliderClass = (swiper: Swiper) => {
  if (!isDesktopSize && !swiper.isBeginning && !swiper.isEnd) {
   swiper.$wrapperEl.addClass(styles.swiperWrapperMobile);
  } else {
   swiper.$wrapperEl.removeClass(styles.swiperWrapperMobile);
  }
 }
```

Answer (score -2):

If you want to show 2 half slides and 2 full slides you can use the config like

slidesPerView: 1.5 , centeredSlides: true

Comment: This is not the answer of the question, your solution is producing 1 slide full in center and 2 half slides on the left and right.

Comment: this doesn't work as you're thinking in comparison to the answer